Interpreting AutoArima output
I am using AutoArima from the pmdarima python module to perform model selection for a time series using AIC. The function returns a model described by the notation
SARIMAX(1, 1, 0)x(2, 0, [1], 7). What do the square brackets mean? i.e. what is the meaning of $Q=[1]$? Is this standard notation for something?
Doing something experiments, I have even seen outputs like SARIMAX(1, 1, 0)x(2, 0, [1, 2], 7), with multiple numbers in square brackets.
This prior question from stack exchange is more or less the same. I am raising it again because the given answer does not actually explain the meaning of the brackets.

This is very strange indeed. Can you post a minimal (!) reproducible (!) example? For instance, using random data both for the actuals and the predictor(s), and playing around with the RNG seed until you get an example of this behavior.
